# Canvas, загрузка картинок

Tags: javascript, canvas

появилась задачка по работе с Canvas, особо с ним никогда не работал, но сразу столкнулся с моментом который мне не особо нравится.

Дело в картинках, как быть с загрузкой картинок, если их может быть большое количество.

Как избежать огромного дублирования кода

```
let image1 = new Image();
image1.src = '';

let image2 = new Image();
image2.src = '';

let image3 = new Image();
image3.src = '';
```

Собственно какие есть пути решения данной проблемы?

UPD: Кто что скажет про такую релизацию?

```
function getImage(imgNum) {
    let images = ['images/image1.png', 'images/image2.png']

    let selectedImage = new Image();
    selectedImage.src = images[imgNum];

    return selectedImage;
}

console.log(getImage(0));
console.log(getImage(1));
```

Comment: используйте массив

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, обновил вопрос, что думаете про такую реализацию?:

Comment: а если картинка не загрузится?

Comment: @Дмытрык действительно, не продумал

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Из вопроса не очень понятно что Вы собираетесь делать с картинками, вот пример как их дружно нарисовать, общий смысл в трансформации массива с урлами в массив с картинками

```js
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

let pic = i => `https://picsum.photos/id/${i}/100/100`

let images = [pic(33), pic(44), pic(55), pic(66), pic(77)];

images = images.map((src, i) => {
  let img = new Image();
  img.src = src;
  img.onload = e => draw(i);
  return img ;
});

function draw(index){
  ctx.drawImage(images[index], index * 110, Math.random()*75)
}
```

```html
<canvas width=600 height=175 id=canvas>
```

Comment: Ничего специфического с ними делать не собираюсь, у меня в классе есть метод для рисования, соответственно различные картинки будут отрисовыватся в разных местах в разное время, цель вопроса именно в сокращении и удобстве кода)

Answer (score 4):

Можно решить примерно так. 
В **src** храним ссылки на картинки. В цикле перебираем каждую ссылку и создаем объект **Image**. Добавляем в массив **images**.

```
let images = [];    
let src = ['link1.com/image.png', 'link2.com/image.png'];

for (let i = 0; i < src.length; i++) {
    let image = new Image();
    image.src = src[i];
    images.push(image);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, вы тоже подсказали интересное решение